# Ошибка при добавление поля на событие bitrix 16.5?

Tags: sql, битрикс

Переходим на новую версию php 7 в bitrix 16.5 и я пытаюсь записать в базу имя физического лица при помощи кода:

https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/c2dfaf819de9d9b65a18b0264757c3a0

Однако происходит сбой записи. Пробовал менять события, пробовал просто отправить, результат один и тот же. Запись заблокирована.
Пытался даже использовать совет:

http://fmwd.ru/stati/cms/1c-bitrix/pochemu-ne-rabotaet-csaleorderpropsvalue.html

Но запись в базу не происходит. Однако все прекрасно пишет в кеш. Вопрос состоит в том, как записать эту информацию базу, аналогично OnOrderSave:

https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/995446e77fedf29014d5bfa640734b94

Comment: Жду CodeReview по ответу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ответ  на вопрос:

```
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->
        addEventHandler("sale", "OnSaleOrderBeforeSaved", "OnSHandler");

function OnSHandler(Bitrix\Main\Event $event) {
    $order = $event->getParameter("ENTITY");
    $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();
    foreach ($propertyCollection->getGroups() as $group) {
        foreach ($propertyCollection->getGroupProperties($group['ID']) as $property) {
            $p = $property->getProperty();

            if (15 == $p["ID"]) {
                $family = $property->getField("VALUE");
            }

            if (19 == $p["ID"]) {
                $name = $property->getField("VALUE");
            }

            if ("PRIVATE_PERSON" == $p["CODE"]) {
                $property->setValue($name . ' ' . $family);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Публикую с целью CodeReview.
Поддержка ответила:

> ЦИТАТА  Вам не нужно писать в базу в этом событии. Вам нужно просто
>   взять коллекцию свойств объекта $order и дописать в нее свои данные,
>   или изменить уже существующие. Система сама потом сохранит всё в базу:
>
> $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();
>
> $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();
>
> foreach ($propertyCollection->getGroups() as $group)  {
>
> foreach ($propertyCollection->getGroupProperties($group['ID']) as
>   $property)  {
>
> $p = $property->getProperty();  if( $p["CODE"] == "CONTACT_PERSON") 
>   $property->setValue("VASYA");
>
> }  }
>
> С уважением,  ведущий специалист отдела  технической поддержки 
>   Шестопалов Лев

При этом мы использовали событие OnSaleOrderBeforeSaved.

Допилить мне его помог:

https://mrcappuccino.ru/blog/post/work-with-basket-bitrix-d7

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, помогло только это:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761140/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-trouble

В результате составил прямой запрос:

```
 $strSql = "INSERT INTO `b_sale_order_props_value`
 SET `ORDER_ID`=" . $value_id . ",
 `ORDER_PROPS_ID`=" . $ar['ID'] . ",
 `NAME`='PRIVATE_PERSON',
 `VALUE`='" . $PRIVATE_PERSON_VALUE . "'
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `NAME`='PRIVATE_PERSON',
 `VALUE`='" . $PRIVATE_PERSON_VALUE . "';"
```

Который отправил в базу и всё работает. Почему происходит другой запрос в штатной функции bitrix.
Я написал запрос в bitrix, возможно еще дополню.

Comment: Это очень похоже на костыль, причем довольно грязненький, который может потом выйти боком.
Вы эту проблему репортили в битрикс как баг?

Answer (score 1):

Так а при чем здесь PHP7. У вас черным по белому пишет: нарушение уникальности ключа IX_SOPV_ORD_PROP_UNI. Это не зависит от версии PHP ни коим образом. По всему похоже, что есть некий тригер срабатывающий на обновление записив этой таблице. Вам надо с этим разбираться... Возможно что то не так у вас обновилось при серьезном обновлении или где то обращаетесь к БД в обход АПИ и там что то нкосячили.

Comment: Все было бы круто не будь это при апдейте.

Comment: Мне нужен пример добавления события на добавление в корзину, а не совет из -серии, что-то там нарушает уникальность ключа. Судя по всему её нарушаю я. Вопрос почему?

Comment: Потом эту ошибку можно игнорировать

Comment: https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0+1062+Duplicate+entry+for+key+PRIMARY+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: и что? Апдейт идет одной таблицы - она тянет за собой изменения в другой и там происходит нарушение целостности. "Почему" надо смотреть данные в вашей базе. Найти к какой таблице относится этот индекс. Подумать как они взаимосвязаны с той которую обновляет и уже на основе полученной информации делать дальнейший вывод.
Вот пример https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/events/sale_entitysaved.php  , но вы его наверняка видели.... Поймете почему возникает нарушение целостности - решите свою задачу...

Comment: Можно игнорирвать ошибку нарушения целостности ключа?!!  Приведенная вами ссылка относится вообще к репликации это во первых. А во вторых... "можно"... только если вам данные "для мебели нужны"... Для рабочей базы это недопустимо...